# Makefile for custom raspberry pi OS not working

Tags: c, makefile, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to make a custom OS for the raspberry pi. I follow [this tutorial](https://jsandler18.github.io/tutorial/organize.html) and used their Makefile, but when I try to compile it, I get this error:

```
echo  objects/kernel.o  objects/uart.o  objects/stdio.o  objects/stdlib.o  objects/boot.o
 objects/kernel.o  objects/uart.o  objects/stdio.o  objects/stdlib.o  objects/boot.o
./gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -T linker.ld -o kernel.img -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib  objects/kernel.o  objects/uart.o  objects/stdio.o  objects/stdlib.o  objects/boot.o
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, ./gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -T linker.ld -o kernel.img -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib objects/kernel.o objects/uart.o objects/stdio.o objects/stdlib.o objects/boot.o, ...) failed.
make (e=2): Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (Translation: The system can't find the given file)
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'build' failed
mingw32-make: *** [build] Error 2
```

and the Makefile:

```
# Don't use normal gcc, use the arm cross compiler
CC = ./gcc-arm-none-eabi-6-2017-q2-update/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc

# Set any constants based on the raspberry pi model.  Version 1 has some differences to 2 and 3
ifeq ($(RASPI_MODEL),1)
    CPU = arm1176jzf-s
    DIRECTIVES = -D MODEL_1
else
    CPU = cortex-a7
endif

CFLAGS= -mcpu=$(CPU) -fpic -ffreestanding $(DIRECTIVES)
CSRCFLAGS= -O2 -Wall -Wextra
LFLAGS= -ffreestanding -O2 -nostdlib

# Location of the files
KER_SRC = ../src/kernel
KER_HEAD = ../include
COMMON_SRC = ../src/common
OBJ_DIR = objects
KERSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.c)
COMMONSOURCES = $(wildcard $(COMMON_SRC)/*.c)
ASMSOURCES = $(wildcard $(KER_SRC)/*.S)
OBJECTS = $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(KERSOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(COMMONSOURCES))
OBJECTS += $(patsubst $(KER_SRC)/%.S, $(OBJ_DIR)/%.o, $(ASMSOURCES))
HEADERS = $(wildcard $(KER_HEAD)/*.h)

IMG_NAME=kernel.img


build: $(OBJECTS) $(HEADERS)
    echo $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -T linker.ld -o $(IMG_NAME) $(LFLAGS) $(OBJECTS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(KER_SRC)/%.S
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(COMMON_SRC)/%.c
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(KER_SRC) -I$(KER_HEAD) -c $< -o $@ $(CSRCFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
    rm $(IMG_NAME)

run: build
    qemu-system-arm -m 1024 -M raspi2 -serial stdio -kernel kernel.img
```

But because I've never worked with Makefiles before, I don't know what is wrong with the Makefile

Comment: `./` means the path starts in the current directory. You probably should use an absolute path to `gcc` instead.

Comment: okay that worked, but now it tells me, that the directories "-p" and "objects" already exist

Comment: If you have another question, plese use the "ask a question" button to ask another question.